# How to set default class for <pre> tag in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

I just implemented syntax highlighter Google prettify script. However in order to highlight the syntax of existing posts I need to add class "prettyprint" like this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint>
//code here
</pre>
```

Is there any way to set the prettyprint as a default class for all the  tags so that the old posts code gets highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use jQuery for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('pre').addClass("prettyprint");
});
```

It will add class to all `pre`element on document ready.

Comment: Thanks Zaheer!! I am trying to implement it on my site. I will update you if it works